# Auto update of column in SQL Server 2008 table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm creating an airline reservation website viz used for one month advance booking so how to store no of seats available for particular dates in SQL Server 2008

Comment: You need to provide more information and format your question better to make it answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking here, you will have to clarify if this is not what you're asking. Are you asking what is best practice?

One way would be to put total number of seats related to each flight in a column under a 'flights' table. Then, another table with each reservation. Then you can just subtract each reservation from the flights column. So you would hvae two columns like this:

```
--------------------------------------
| id  | flight_number | num_of_seats |
--------------------------------------
```

and then a second column called reservations for example:

```
-------------------------------------------------
| id | user_id | reservation_num | flight_number|
-------------------------------------------------
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You got it as in you figured it out or this answer solved it? If this answer solved it, pelase use the check mark to indicate. If you figured it out, please post as an answer so others can learn from it.